# Cannot reinitialise DataTable error when trying to set class

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am working on a program, Where, on the click of a tab, I retrieve data and populate my datatables.

So on the click of this item, I call the getOutPutData function, which goes to my controller and then populates a data table of ID tblStock.

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#wizard-simple-step3" data-toggle="tab" onclick="getOutPutData();">3. Extra</a>
</li>
```

// Function below.

```
    var isFirst = true;
    console.log(isFirst);
    function getOutPutData() {
        console.log(isFirst);
        if ($("#id").val() == null || $("#id").val().toString().length <= 0 || parseInt($("#id").val()) <= 0) {
        jAlert("Please Save Tab Details First!!!");
    }
        else {
            if (isFirst) {
                $('#tblStock').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "@Url.Action("getOutPutData", "PSIPDetails")",
                        "data": { "id": $('#id').val() },
                        "type": "POST"
                    }
                });

             //   getOutComeData();

            } 
              isFirst = false; 
        }
    }
```

Continuing the explanation, When this happens, the tab that was clicked, loads a page where the table with the tblStock ID exist.

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="wizard-simple-step3">
     <div>
         @Html.Action("Output", "PSIPDetails", new { id = Model.id })
     </div>
</div>
```

Then on this page I have the table

```
<div class="table" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="tblStock" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full" style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <td>Output</td>
                        <td>Output Description</td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem ultimately boils down to this line `class="js-dataTable-full"` I need this added to implement the styles, yet when i run it I get the error "DataTables warning: table id=tblStock - Cannot reinitialise DataTable" upon googling the error, https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3 it mentioned that the table cannot be reinitialise once done a first time. Now I'm assuming that first is when i set it's data in the getOutPutData function but I am unsure how to set the class there. The link and other questions talk of destroying the table, but I am unsure how that will work or where I should destroy it.

Please guide.

Comment: In your function `getOutPutData()` this bit of code `$('#tblStock').DataTable({` is instantiating a datatable on the `tblStock` DOM element, which i assume is a table. Basically your problem is that you're calling `getOutPutData()` more than once or triggering the click even more than once.

Comment: @bassxzero I added a check to handle that

Answer (score 0):

### Initialize Datatable once

This code block:

```
let myDatatable = $('#tblStock').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "@Url.Action("getOutPutData", "PSIPDetails")",
        "data": { "id": $('#id').val() },
        "type": "POST"
    }
});
```

...needs to be initialized before your `getOutPutData()` function is called, in order to avoid to initialize your datatable more than once.

Then replace this code by using [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()):

```
myDatatable.ajax.reload();
```

You may have to adapt that a bit, but that's the start of the way you should going.

---

### Add a class to the Datatable

If classes added through HTML is not persistent after datatable initialization, you can add these after thanks to [`table().container()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table().container()).

```
// After datatable initialization
$(myDatatable.table().container()).addClass('firstClass secondClass');
```

**Or**, as you put an ID, just selecting it with jQuery should directly work:
*(if not, please tell me)*

```
$('#tblStock').addClass('firstClass secondClass');
```

Comment: I added a check to handle that for now, to avoid the double initialize. but my query still exist on how to add a class to the table.

Comment: Edited. Didn't see that question!

Comment: Last paragraph .